# Is it possible to prevent the deletion of taxonomy by detecting $_GET request

Tags: taxonomy

Hooks are good and all, but I want to prevent the deletion of taxonomy by detecting $_GET requests

```
if(isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && isset($_REQUEST['taxonomy'])) {
    if($_REQUEST['action'] === 'delete') {
        wp_die($notice);
    }
}
```

I am currently using this same approach for pages, users, and posts but it doesn't seem to work for taxonomy.

When I click the delete button on the WordPress admin page for wp-admin/edit-tags.php, the term gets deleted. The first if-statement seems to evaluate to true but the second one seems to evaluate to false for some reason.

I am aware of using hooks to detect before a taxonomy is deleted, but I don't want to use that approach unless there a good reason.

Any idea why the above code does not prevent a taxonomy from being deleted?

Comment: Seems like a good reason to use hooks, but anyway. Where did you put this if check?, if its in the theme folder, and without action/filter, it will not affect the dashboard in anyway.

Comment: “unless there a good reason” Because it’s the proper supported way for handling stuff like this. Why would you deliberately want to do things the wrong way? It Jutland makes it far more likely that it won’t work in the future or current edge cases.

Comment: I put it in functions

Comment: Without a proper action it wont work, you can throw a if block in functions.php and expect it to work. This what hooks are used for, and other things. Find the proper action (most likely a action) and do what validations you need there.

Comment: I get what you're saying, hooks are appropriate. But it would still be nice to know why my $_REQUEST checks work for deleting users but not taxonomy